# How to create a folder in CAPL to save Pictures?

Tags: capl

How do I create a folder in CAPL to save Pictures?

This is for CAPL:

`setFilePath("..\\album_covers" , 1);`  This doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
on key 't'
{
      sysExecCmd("mkdir C:\\Projects\\CANoe\\some_script_to_execute && exit","");
}
```